# How to iterate over two arrays and delete matching values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm trying to iterate over two arrays in my Ruby on Rails program and create a new array with the objects that shouldn't be excluded.

Here is my object array that I need to iterate over:

```
[#<Result id: 1437, network_host_test_id: 1320, issue_id: 50231, created_at: "2016-04-14 19:30:22", updated_at: "2016-04-27 18:08:00", deleted_at: nil>,
 #<Result id: 1438, network_host_test_id: 1320, issue_id: 47573, created_at: "2016-04-14 19:30:22", updated_at: "2016-04-14 19:30:22", deleted_at: nil>,
 #<Result id: 1439, network_host_test_id: 1320, issue_id: 39758, created_at: "2016-04-14 19:30:22", updated_at: "2016-04-14 19:30:22", deleted_at: nil>,
 #<Result id: 1441, network_host_test_id: 1320, issue_id: 47574, created_at: "2016-04-14 19:30:22", updated_at: "2016-04-14 19:30:22", deleted_at: nil>,
 #<Result id: 1442, network_host_test_id: 1320, issue_id: 50442, created_at: "2016-04-14 19:30:22", updated_at: "2016-04-14 19:30:22", deleted_at: nil>,
 #<Result id: 1443, network_host_test_id: 1320, issue_id: 40991, created_at: "2016-04-14 19:30:22", updated_at: "2016-04-14 19:30:22", deleted_at: nil>,
 #<Result id: 1444, network_host_test_id: 1320, issue_id: 43896, created_at: "2016-04-14 19:30:22", updated_at: "2016-04-14 19:30:22", deleted_at: nil>]
```

My exclude array is:

```
[#<DeferredIssue id: 1, defer_reason: "Test for issue", defer_name: "JF", issue_id: 50231, created_at: "2016-04-28 17:50:37", updated_at: "2016-04-28 17:50:37", network_host_id: 76>,
 #<DeferredIssue id: 2, defer_reason: "Defer a 10", defer_name: "Travis", issue_id: 43896, created_at: "2016-04-28 17:51:25", updated_at: "2016-04-28 17:51:25", network_host_id: 76>]
```

In the end, my array should not have objects with the `issue_id` of `50231` or `43896`.

I tested this out initially using  `exclude?`, but my exclude array was just `[50231, 43896]`.  Now that they are objects, that type of iteration doesn't work.

What is the Ruby way to do this type of thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can transform your array to an array of `issue_ids` with `map`:

```
ids = exclude_array.map(&:issue_id)
#=> [50231, 43896]
your_objects.select {|o| ids.exclude?(o.issue_id) }
```

Comment: @Godzilla74, is it what are you asked about?

Comment: Totally... worked like a charm... can mark it right in a few minutes.

Comment: May not be worth it, this could also mean looping over a lot of excluded IDs if they are identical, you could do `exclude_array.map(&:issue_id).uniq` but probably an over optimization